# Where do I sort?

Tags: java, sql, mysql, sorting

I have a database, which I query, and I'm unsure of where to perform the sorting of the results, so far I've have the following options.

- At the MySQL query.
- At list level(Using a LinkedList)
- Sorting an unsorted list using comparators before showing the results (basically in the jsp)

The List is composed by ObjectDTO so where would it be more efficient. Any ideas?

Comment: Note that you usually would like to avoid Java code in JSP files. So, the last point can can better be "basically in the servlet".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should do the sorting in the database if at all possible.

- The database can use indexes. If there is a suitable index available then the results can be read from disk already in sorted order, resulting in a performance increase - no extra O(n log(n)) sorting step is required.
- If you only need the first `x` results you also minimize data transfer (both reduced network transfer, and also reduced disk access if there is a suitable index).

Comment: So should I use a LinkedList for keeping the insertion order?

Comment: @Triztian: an `ArrayList` is better for fast retrieval. A `LinkedList` is only faster for removal (which you don't need if the sole purpose is to display the results).

Comment: Hmm, didn't know that, I've read the Interfaces and abstracts about list and collections but sometimes its confusing

Comment: So, in a nutshell this is what I want to do.
Query the database, something like this:
<code>
   SELECT* FROM order WHERE user = 'triztian' ORDER BY 'mycolumn' ASC;
</code>  
then, I would map the result-set fields to a DTO Object and then insert the DTO Object to a List, finally I would like to show that list retaining the order in which the elements where inserted into it.

Comment: @Mark Byers, re point 2: not only data transfer - if there is an index that can be used then it directly cuts I/O operations - you might cut query execution time many times = huge win (plus it minimizes transfer).

Comment: @Unreason: +1 Thanks for the comment - you are exactly correct - I've fixed it now. :)

Answer (score 16):

Database. Using indexes and other information about the data, db's are very good at this.

Answer (score 0):

Best is at the mySQL query.

a) It is easy to do

b) If you use an index the sort happens when the index is created or when new rows are inserted automatically (sometimes an index needs a reorganization but this is a db admins daily business. This applies if the table is very huge.).

e) If the index includes the columns used in the where clause the access in general is faster

d) You do not need to read the whole table each time to do the sort for yourself

e) Even if you have no index I believe the DB can do the sorting best

Hope it helps